Does static initialization order fiasco apply to global variables without static?
i have some code example, in the function insert_id i got an empty string. After a lot of research it might be the  initialization order fiasco, but i am not sure because the variable is only an const variable.
const std::string c_const_txt = "test string";


tc::tc()
{
    m_state_ok = false;
    std::cout << "date: " << __DATE__ << " time " << __TIME__ << std::endl
    m_id = insert_id(c_const_txt);
}

Could here happen the init order fiasco?
thanks
If i change the std::string to const char* i got the right string in the insert_id function.

SIOF happens when you use one global object to initialise another global object in a different translation unit (i.e., a different .cpp file). It's unspecified in which order they will be initialised, so it's entirely possible you will use uninitialised object.

I would generally be extremely careful with stuff that runs before main -- in particular, I wouldn't trust std::cout to be available either... also, in case a string is not necessary and C++20 is available, have you tried using a constinit std::string_view instead?

string literal would be likely static initialization

This code do not contain SIOF. Also static keyword in this context doesn't change anything. In context of global variable static means: this symbol will be visible only in current translation unit. This doesn't impact initialization. In fact const for global variable implicitly adds static.

In "static initialization order fiasco", the key concept is "static initialization", as a whole (vs "dynamic initialization"). That it has some overlap with the static keyword in the C/C++ language is just coincidental.

Okay, that make sense the SIOF means the kind of initialization the variable, and not the keyword static. Thanks!

@ChristianStieber -- std::cout and the rest of the standard streams are required to be usable during static initialization. Standard library implementations jump through hoops to get that to work. The portable (and inefficient) way to do that is the nifty counter trick; compilers provide their own mechanisms to manage order of construction of static objects, and library implementors know how to do this.

Yksisarvinen has a good answer. @Yksisarvinen consider giving an answer for posterity.
